# Tree of categories

Tags: laravel

I have three tables: Category, Subcategory, Subsubcategory.

I need to make a tree of categories with many relationships, that means:

```
-Category
   --Subcategory
   --Subcategory
       ---Subsubcategory
       ---Subsubcategory
  --Subcategory
-Category
-Category
```

I've made three model as like tables; 
Now I need to collect all categories with subcategories of subsubcategories.

How to do this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It sounds like pretty bad design to create three tables for this. Make a single table with a reference to the top level category where toplevel categories have a NULL parent.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that you will have only 3 levels of the categories tree?

What I've done in such cases is I use one table which has an additional parent id, so if the parent id is 0 that means it is the root of the tree, a child in the tree like your subcategory will contain 1 for the parent id and so on. So something like this:

```
1. Category (parent 0)
   3. Subcategory (parent 1)
      4. Subsubcategory (parent 3)
2. Category (parent 0)
```

then you can recursively display them or use them.

This is only one model (table) called Category, and the example above uses their names.